# Copy more than 65000 characters

Tags: sql-server, excel

How is it possible to extend the clipboard and copy more than 65K characters? For instance, if you have a large dataset (in Excel) and you copy and insert it into SQL - Server in order to create a table with that data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the data import tools in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: in my SSMS 2014 i can copy-paste 1M file without any problems

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard to populate SQL?

Comment: IMO we need an off-topic flag reason for http://dba.stackexchange.com. This is not about programming, just using a DBMS frontend.

Comment: either use data tools or import function. Not exactly sure what you are attempting to paste and to where?